# Effect of Quantisation of a Signal on the Estimated Spectrum

Tags: signal, fourier, spectrum

I have been applying the Welch Estimation technique to a signal in MATLAB to give a Spectral Density plot for frequencies from 0 to 0.5 the sample rate. I have two issues:

1. I have a peak at 0.25 for all my signals, is this likely a result of the estimation technique at its half the frequency range?
2. I have noted my signal is digitised, what effect does this have on the spectral estimation?

Comment: Can you share the sample rate, the number of points in each epoch used for the periodogram, and the number of epochs?  Did you detrend each epoch?

Comment: The sample rate is 1Hz. The sample size is about 86000 and ive used Welch overlapping windows of 16384=2^14 with 50% overlap. ive removed the data mean but not any linear trend (i can try this but there doesnt appear an obvious linear effect)

Comment: I was just trying to get a feel for if you were talking about one of your frequency endpoints, but you're smack dab in the middle at 0.25 Hz, aren't you?  I seem to remember something a bit odd about calculating the freq. axis.  I recommend creating a clean signal of 0.2 Hz and running the periodogram on that, just as a reality check.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the quantization is your problem, but how was the data collected?  Have you condidered the possibility of some higher frequency noise aliasing down to 0.25 Hz?  I had that problem once at a much higher frequency, where a funny spike worked its way in to the data, and it turned out to be aliased from a much higher frequency, despite 8-pole Butterworths on every input to the DAC.  Are you anti-alias filtering?